# Privat Route is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i try to make an simple login page. I tried several thing for the Routing, but i didn't get it... right now my code looks like this and i get the error:

```
[PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

This is my app.js

```
// App.js
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Account from "./Account";
import FreeComponent from "./FreeComponent";
import AuthComponent from "./AuthComponent";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import Register from "./Register";
import Login from "./Login";

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>

      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Account />} />
        <Route exact path="/free" element={<FreeComponent />} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/auth" element={<AuthComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my PrivateRoute.js

```
// PrivateRoute.js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");

        if (token) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Navigate
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location || "/"
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

So my goal is that if someone goes to the page /auth he should be redirected to the / path

Any one has an idea why it isn't working? Tried several things but nothing worked for me.

I tried to change the Private Route, tried to change it to switch and back